# Problem in install gtest, can not compile it due to huge errors

Tags: compilation, googletest

Tons of compile errors occur when make.

What I did are itemized:
My operation is shown itemized:

```
yum install git
yum install gcc-c++
yum install cmake
yum install python
yum install zeromq-devel
```

Then ： 
    git clone https://github.com/google/googletest.git

```
cd /googletest/googletest


[root@VM_16_11_centos googletest]# cmake CMakeLists.txt
 -- Configuring done
 -- Generating done
 -- Build files have been written to: 
 /usr/local/qiuxin/googletest/googletest
`[root@VM_16_11_centos googletest]# make
Huge Error here!!!
In file included from 
/usr/local/qiuxin/googletest/googletest/src/gtest-all.cc:38:0:
/usr/local/qiuxin/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h: In 
member function 'virtual 
testing::Test::Setup_should_be_spelled_SetUp* 
testing::Test::Setup()':
```

Comment: /usr/local/qiuxin/googletest/googletest/include/gtest/gtest.h:513:68: 
    error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return- 
    type]
    virtual Setup_should_be_spelled_SetUp* Setup() { return nullptr; }
    ^
    cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/all] Error 2
    make: *** [all] Error 2`

Comment: Please include the error in the question, not in comments. You can always edit your question and add additional information.

Answer (score 0):

solved. The mistake I made was:
1） I created a build folder in the googletest/googletest directory.

The right operation should be:

Create a build folder in googletest directory(NOT googletest/googletest directory.).
then:
cd build
cmake .. -DBUILD_GTEST=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON
make
sudo make install
Everything goes well!